# Azure AD B2C Phone/Email password reset

Tags: email, azure-ad-b2c, reset-password

For my .NET 5 application I am trying to setup Azure AD B2C with local account identity provider with following assumptions:

- user accounts are being created for users by administrators, they can have email address or phone number
- possibility to login with phone number with One-Time-Password
- possibility to login with email and at **first login there is email verification with code and password reset/setup**

I created userflow for phoneNumber/email, phone logging with OTP is working fine, the problem is with bolded part of last bullet. There is possibility to enable Self-Service-Password-Reset within just an email as local account identity provider userflow and it is working out of the box. But having selected Email/PhoneNumber local account identity provider there is no possibility to get use of that benefit.

I tried to make it as 2 separate userflows: Sign-In and Password-Reset. Again - phone login is working, but while trying to reset email account password I am receiving **AADB2C90037** error from Azure.

Is it possible to meet such assumptions using userflow? I checked MS docs and couldn't find explicit anwser. If no, I am assuming I must use custom policy? In that scenario would it be better to use separate sign-in userflow and password reset custom policy, or single sign-in custom policy?
Regards

Comment: Please check the Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows) under Supported account types Section.

Answer (score 0):

**I Tried to reproduce the same in my environment to reset the password using email in Azure AD B2C, As I got below screen.**

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiAAn.png)

> Note: Make sure add the Azure B2C password reset policy in Visual Studio
> Ex: password reset policy name, such as *B2C_1_pwd_reset*.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/osJTP.png)

Create Application in Azure B2C Tenant
Go to Azure B2C **Portal->Manage-> App registrations ->New Registration->Supported account types**

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bb1lK.png)

Create a user flow:

Email-Password-reset for resetting the password.
**Azure B2C Portal ->Policies ->Password Reset -> Recomended under Version**

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag4rr.png)

***Edit below VS Code as per the Values to reset the password using Email. ***

```
"AzureAdB2c": {  
"Instance": "https://Tenant Name.b2clogin.com/%22",  
"Domain": "Domain Name",  
"TenantId": "Tenant ID",  
"ClientId": "App Cleint ID",  
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",  
"SignUpSignInPolicyId": "Signinsignup user flow Name",   
"ResetPasswordPolicyId": "Reset User Flow Name", 
},  
"Logging": {  
"LogLevel": {  
"Default": "Information",  
"Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"  
}  
},  
"AllowedHosts": "*"  
}
```

Run the Visual Studio application and Click on Login/Forgot password,it will redirect to the below page.
Use the existing account credentials to reset the password using email.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IM7b.png)

Comment: Was it working for you with phone/email local account sign in? As mentioned above - I tried this way and I am receiving AADB2C90037 error from azure while I want to use password reset from link 'Forgot your password?'

Comment: Hi snilmerg, yes, it's working for me, kindly define the User password flow value in Visual Code to reset the password from application. If do not pass the same value, you will get the same error.